# Count riemann events in given time window

Tags: clojure, riemann

In riemann config for specific service I'm trying to assign to all its events metric=1, sum them within 5sec and send the result to influxdb.

I tried the following:

```
(streams
  (where (service "offers")
    (fixed-time-window 5
      (smap folds/sum (with :metric 1 index))))
  influx)
```

It doesn't really work, events stored in influx do not match this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in `folds/count` function does this:

```
(fixed-time-window 5
  (smap folds/count influx))
```

also the call to influx needs to be a child of the stream that does the counting so it's the counts that get indexed.

If you want to fix your example using `folds/sum` you could move the call to `(with :metric 1)` outside, or upstream of, the call to sum so the metrics are set to one and then the new metrics are summed in the call to `folds/sum`. Then put the call to index and or influx as the child stream of smap so the summed items get indexed and forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by Arthur, you might want to use [`rate`](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-rate) (with [`scale`](http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html#var-scale)) instead of `fixed-time-window` (with `smap` and `folds/count`). `rate` is generally better than `fixed-time-window` because `rate` fires as soon as the time window has finished, while `fixed-time-window` has to wait until a new event arrives after the time window has finished, which can never happen or happen too far in the future. There's an [issue in riemann](https://github.com/aphyr/riemann/issues/563) about this.

There's also a [comment from aphyr](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/riemann-users/3yWmtAehqoA/7lyuiLXgz70J) explaining why `rate` is more efficient than the windowing functions.

You just need to use it with `scale` because `rate` will measure the rate by second while you want to get the rate by 5 seconds (measured during a 5 seconds interval).

Comment: thanks for suggestion. you meant something like ```(rate 5 (scale 5 influx))``` ?

Comment: I am confused . Still unable to count events in rate using scale. I have variable values of metrics , where I tried to calculate the average of metrics in rate of 10.